# Memory leak in silverlight prism/unity

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, unity-container, prism

We are building a LOB application using SL4, PRISM and MVVM. I noticed very lately that my App is not releasing any memory. It starts around 150MB and grows to 1 GB+ very fast if I switch b/w pages. Our design involves 3 modules each having a Controller class (Unity singleton) which listens for events and injects views into the appropriate region. So this is whats happening in those controllers when an event is fired to inject a view.

```
var v = Container.resolve<view>()
var vm = Container.resolve<viewmodel>()
v.datacontext = vm;
myregion.addtoregion(v);
```

so 100 calls for this view will exceute this 100 times. And in addviewregion method, I'm removing all existing views before adding the new one. And after seeing the memory problem, I set both view & viewmodel to null in addviewtoregion method for all the views needed to be removed. Still memory consumption is same. 
Is Unity ContainerControllled... objects (my controllers) holding references to these objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you registering to handle events on these dynamic views and forgetting to unregister them before you remove the view? Handling an event creates an implicit reference to the object, and that is typically where managed memory leaks come from.

You should check out [this guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/03/11/where-s-your-leak-at-using-windbg-sos-and-gcroot-to-diagnose-a-net-memory-leak.aspx) to tracking down leaky Silverlight controls using [WinDbg](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx) to examine the heap and GC roots.

Comment: this is a likely cause. you should use weak event handling for Event Aggregator events

Comment: It looks like the unity resolved objects are not getting garbage collected or something is wrong with my Container configuration. I tested with the following code:

Comment: WeakReference ref1 = new WeakReference(Container.Resolve<Footer>());
WeakReference ref2 = new WeakReference(new Footer());
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
bool isRef1Alive = ref1.IsAlive;
bool isRef2Alive = ref2.IsAlive;

Footer is a UserControl and here first one returns true whereas the second one returns false. Does Container holds any reference to the item it resolves? BTW, i dont have any interfaces for this view. I added
Container.RegisterType<Footer, Footer>();
in the Bootstrapper(ConfigureContainer method). still same result.

Comment: As far as I understand weak references they are not garbage collected when you think they should be collectde but when the GC thinks the referenced memory is used. Unity objects get garbage collected as far as they aren't used anymore.